# Uploading S3 using AWS SDK Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jsp, amazon-s3

my current setup is like this

```
  AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client();

  InputStream stream = new URL(filePath).openStream();

  ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
  PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(amazonFileUploadLocationOriginal, keyName, stream, objectMetadata);

  PutObjectResult result = s3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest);
```

And I'm always getting this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed
```

And I know it is caused by calling

```
 HttpEntity.getContent()
```

multiple times

But I can't seem to debug/find where it is being called multiple times

Answer (score 0):

From [PutObjectRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html#PutObjectRequest%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream,%20com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata%29) doc

> metadata - The object metadata. At minimum this specifies the content
>   length for the stream of data being uploaded.

I had never used an input stream from an URL, but looks like you are missing the "length for the stream".

Comment: Hi, do you any idea on how the get the stream length? What I'm feeding via the input steam is a file URL.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are uploading from a file, you could use [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html#PutObjectRequest%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) constructor for the PutObjectRequest:

```
 File theFile = new File(filePath);
 PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(amazonFileUploadLocationOriginal, keyName, theFile);
 putObjectRequest.withMetadata(objectMetadata);
```