# How to upload S3 Objects in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I use JAVA SDK, I have create one web application that describes html file & target to upload file from html to AWS SDK using jsp ? is it possible

Comment: hi, is this not kinda duplicate with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24549685/uploading-s3-using-aws-sdk-java?

Comment: Hi, but how can i get absolute path on <input type="file">

Comment: oh I see, I have not done java for a while but you should play with streams I guess. What did you try so far, can you paste the code you tried with potential errors?

Comment: Sure, In short when i try to upload object <input type="file"> i can't get the absolute path, so how can i use PutObjectRequest if i unable to locate full path ? that'z the problem

Answer (score 0):

When you retrieve the file from the input field, give it to the PutObject command through an inputStream.

Assuming you stored the file input into a "myFile" variable, then create the PutObjectRequest using *myFile.getInputStream()* as a file